# jQuery how to redirect

Tags: jquery

i m trying to redirect to another page depending on the data that i receive in the callback function of my script.

```
jQuery("button.logInBtn").click(function(){     
    if(jQuery('#userName').val() == "" || jQuery('#password').val() == ""){
        alertify.error("Please enter User Name and Password");  
    }
    else{
        jQuery.post( jQuery("#loginForm").attr("action"), 
                 jQuery("#loginForm :input").serializeArray(),
                 function(data){
                        alertify.success(data);
                 });        
    }
    jQuery("#loginForm").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });

});
```

How can i make this script to check which data i receive in the callback function??? and then redirect depending on the data that i receive

Comment: By writing code, usually. It depends entirely on what type of data you expect to get back, and how you want to redirect. As a starting point, in JavaScript you use `document.location.href=blah;` to redirect.

Comment: can i have that in the callback function if data is equal to something??

Comment: ive tryied before like this

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
jQuery.post( jQuery("#loginForm").attr("action"), 
             jQuery("#loginForm :input").serializeArray(),
             function(data){
                 if(data=="something"){ // replace with your condition
                     document.location.href = "http://example.net"; //redirect to example.net
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help but still not working this is what I got.
`jQuery.post( jQuery("#loginForm").attr("action"), 
           jQuery("#loginForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(data){
         if(data == "match"){ 
                        window.location = "/main/index.php";
                        return true;
                       }
                       else{                        
                         alertify.error(data);
                       }
        }); `

Comment: What does `data` contain? I believe it's about condition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `alertify.success(data)`, with `data` being what comes back from ajax.

You can then redirect with `window.location.href = 'http://example.com'`

A quick way to define `alertify.data` would be:

```
alertify = function() {
  return {
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.username) { //or any other condition
        window.location.href = ...
      };
    };
  };
};
```